# Modify Javascript to get "Page 1 of total pages"

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I'm working on a .pdf form that uses two templates so that the user can add pages at will.  I'm trying to make a button the user pushes at the end so that we get page numbers at the bottom that say Page 1 of Total Page#.
I found some javascript online and modified it a bit, and it gives me the page number:

```
var inch = 72;
for (var p = 0; p < this.numPages; p++) { 
 // put a rectangle at .5 inch, .5 inch 
  var aRect = this.getPageBox( {nPage: p} ); 
  aRect[0] += 4*inch;// from upper left corner of page 
  aRect[2] = aRect[0]+.5*inch; // Make it .5 inch wide 
  aRect[1] -= 10.5*inch; 
  aRect[3] = aRect[1] - .3*inch; // and .5 inch high 
  var f = this.addField("p."+p, "text", p, aRect ); 
  f.textSize = 8;
  f.textColor = color.black; // use whatever color you want
  f.strokeColor = color.white; 
  f.textFont = font.Helv; 
  f.value = String(p+1);  // page numbering is zero-based
  f.readonly = true; 
}
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to modify this further to get it to tell me the total page number.

Comment: you probably want to try `this.numPages` as a starting off point.

Comment: where would I put it.  I only have the most superficial knowledge of javascript.  calling it knowledge is probably hyperbole...

Comment: you can `console.log(this.numPages)` anywhere before, after, or inside of the `for` loop code and see if it is indeed the total pages. if it is, then you can look up how to add a value into the DOM with javascript.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a shot.

Comment: What should I be seeing?  I ask because nothing has changed.  When I click the button on my .pdf document, the page number pops into position, but nothing else has changed.

Comment: sorry, without more of your code I can't really help you anymore. `console.log` messages show up in the developer console. Research how to open up the javascript console for your browser.

Comment: that's actually all of my code.  like i said, this code is tucked into a button on a .pdf.  maybe you're not familiar with how that works. i probably need to find someone who works with .pdf docs.  thanks for your input anyway.

Comment: so, you're using adobe acrobat?

Comment: Yes.  You can use Acrobat or really most (all?) PDF editors to have JavaScript activated by a button.

Comment: try changing the `f.value` line to this: `f.value = String(this.numPages);` that should show you the total pages instead of page number.

Comment: that is very helpful.  you gave me enough info for me to figure it out.  this is what i ended up doing:   f.value = String("Page ")+String(p+1)+String(" of ")+String(this.numPages);  thank you for your help!

Comment: Awesome, you could probably shorten that to just `"String("Page " + (p+1) + " of " + this.numPages);` which is more concise and cleaner.

Comment: I was trying to do something like that, but something was off, so I gave up and just made it ugly. Again, I know almost nothing about JavaScript, so even this was a stretch for me. Thank you again! I couldn't find anyone else to help me, but now my boss thinks I'm some kind of wizard.